# How is the range of multivariate gaussian probability density function scalar?

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, vectors

$ f_{\mathbf{X}}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k}\right)=\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^{k}|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|}}$

I believe $x_1,...x_k \in \mathbb{R}^d$

How is range of $f_{\mathbf{X}}$ a scalar?

Comment: The exponential takes a scalar as input and returns a scalar, and the rest of the expression  is obviously a scalar too. $(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})$ is a scalar even if it involves vectors and a matrix.

Comment: But you have x axis and y axis in multivariate normal. The k inputs have to have both axis coordinates s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\underbrace{(x-\mu)^T}_{1\times k}\underbrace{ \Sigma^{-1}}_{k\times k} \underbrace{(x-\mu)}_{k\times 1}$$

is scalar. Also, $|\Sigma|$, i.e. the determinant of $\Sigma$, is also scalar.